# jest manual ES6 class mock is not active and I want to understand why

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, mocking, vuex

I am having problems using Jest manual mocks (the one in a parallel `__mocks__` directory) in my project.

I think I understand how to use it and it actually works fine if I remove a single line in a file specified in the Jest `setupFiles` array.

In that file a global helper is installed (into `global.createComp`) that uses the vuex store.

This **is** a vue + vuex project but even running the stripped down spec using only jest gives unexpected results.

Can somebody look at my minimal reproducible example repo at https://github.com/thenoseman/jest-manual-mock-not-working, do a `npm i` and `npm run test:unit` and help me understand why the mock is not active?

You can find the line that need to be commented out in `test/unit/support/helpers.js`.
Also the [README](https://github.com/thenoseman/jest-manual-mock-not-working/blob/master/README.md) shows a screenshot and further explains what the problem looks like.

Comment: That you provided a repo is good and may help in debugging but not enough for a good question. It should be fully understandable without navigating to external resources which may become unavailable and make the question unintelligible for future readers. Please, provide all relevant details in the question itself.

Comment: @EstusFlask The prophecy has come true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setupFiles` are evaluated before test files. As [the reference](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array) states,

> A list of paths to modules that run some code to configure or set up the testing environment. Each setupFile will be run once per test file. Since every test runs in its own environment, these scripts will be executed in the testing environment immediately before executing the test code itself.

JavaScript modules are evaluated once on first import. Importing `@/store/modules/internetAtHome` in helpers.js results in importing original `@/api/DslService`.

The mock in test file doesn't affect `@/api/DslService` because it has already been evaluated earlier:

```
jest.mock("@/api/DslService");
import DslService from "@/api/DslService";
```

In case helpers.js needs mocked `@/api/DslService`, `jest.mock` needs to be moved there.

In case helpers.js needs original `@/api/DslService` but tests need mocked one, the module (and any module that depends on it) needs to be re-imported with `jest.resetModules` or `jest.isolatedModules`:

```
jest.mock('@/api/DslService');

let DslService;
jest.isolateModules(() => {
  DslService = require("@/api/DslService").default;
});
...
```

For a module that was imported with original implementation and needs to be re-imported as a mock, `jest.requireMock` can be used, it doesn't need `jest.mock('@/api/DslService')`:

```
let DslService = jest.requireMock("@/api/DslService").default;
...
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for! Thanks you a lot for taking the time. It actually works now by putting the mock where the first "import {}" is talking place.